# How do I add a CMS Static Block Text Box To All Product Listings In Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, admin-panel, static-block

I would like to display a **CMS Static Block** text box at the bottom of all product listings in Magento, but I would need the code to put in **CMS -> Static Blocks** in the admin panel in order to do so.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom theme or a module to do this. In the case of a theme, create the following file:

/app/design/frontend/[Company]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

WIth the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockname">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">id_defined_in_block_admin</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

Your block will then appear at the bottom of all product listing (category) pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can add code in your list.phtml from your theme(template\catalog\product).

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to mention this, but I am using Magento 1.9, not Magento 2.2. I am unfortunately not authorized to upgrade the Magento version from the Magento store of where I am asking this question... :(

Comment: answer updated.